# Constructor initialization vs get set initialization

Tags: c#

> A class object if initialized using a constructor then the member variables can only be accessed only directly (objectname.variablename) via a member method.

And

> If a class object is initialized using get;set; then the member variables can only be accessed only via get;set; properties.

Are these statements true? Or am I missing something here?

Following is the code and the output of the code.

```
using System;
public class emp {

    private int empId = -1;
    private string empName = string.Empty;

    public int PEmpId {
        set;
        get;
    }
    public string PEmpName {
        set;
        get;
    }

    public emp(int i, string str) {
        empId = i;
        empName = str;
    }

    public void empDis(emp e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Id =>{0}<=, Nm =>{1}<=", e.empId, e.empName);
        Console.WriteLine("Id =>{0}<=, Nm =>{1}<=", e.PEmpId, e.PEmpName);
    }

    public emp() {}
}

public class empUsage {

    public void Main() {
        emp e = new emp(1, "R");
        e.empDis(e);
        emp e1 = new emp();
        e1.PEmpId = 1;
        e1.PEmpName = "W";

        e1.empDis(e1);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Id =>1<=, Nm =>R<=  
Id =>0<=, Nm =><=  

Id =>-1<=, Nm =><=  
Id =>1<=, Nm =>W<=
```

Comment: This must be homework or some kind of test question.

Comment: No. It's not. I am trying learn c sharp on my own by coding examples.

Comment: start reading some tutorials as well there are tons of free examples online in regard to tutorials http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/SmartConsoleSetup.aspx

Comment: You could make public members for another possible implementation here,

Comment: This question doesn't seem to make sense. It's not clear what you're asking, because your assertions do not seem to correlate with the code you've written.

Answer (score 4):

Those statements are nonsense. There is no relation between how members are initialised and how you can access them.

The `emp` class has both member variables and properties. If you initialise the member variables you can get the values from the member variables. If you initialise the properties you can get the values from the properties.

The constructor that takes parameters uses those values to initialise the member variables. That means that you have values in the member variables, so you can use those. It doesn't however keep you from also initialising the properties and use those if you like.

Answer (score 1):

True, but your implementation of the get/set is off:

```
public int PEmpId {
    set { empId = value; }
    get { return empId; }
}
public string PEmpName {
    set { empName = value; }
    get { return empName; }
}
```

unless you're wanting "automatic (or implicit) properties", then you don't need the `empId` or `empName` fields.

Comment: *"True,"* What is true, exactly?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, from my reading it's asking the difference between 'fields' and 'properties'

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz  You are right. The get set declaration were off. When i fixed them I was able to access the values via member and via properties.

Thank you for not calling my question and statements "non sense" unlike others and answering.

Comment: @user3594120, I think they weren't calling the code nonsense, but the statements about the ctors are a bit unclear and took me some interpolation to assume what was trying to be said. I don't know where those statements came from, but if from another place, well they could fix them to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

> A class object if initialized using a constructor then the member
>   variables can only be accessed only directly (objectname.variablename)
>   via a member method.
>
> If a class object is initialized using get;set; then the member
>   variables can only be accessed only via get;set; properties.

Both statements are untrue. The way of member initialization is not directly connected to the how you can access them. The latter is specified by the *access modifier* (`private`, `public` etc.) when talking about referencing the members directly. If you make your fields public, then they can be accessed directly by any code using your class, no matter how they were instantiated. On the other hand, if you make them private, then only code inside the class itself has access to them and it's up to you how this access will be implemented. You can expose a getter and/or setter, create a method that will change their values, or both (or none). All these options are possible every time, regardless of the way of initialization.

Answer (score 0):

> Are these statements true?

No.

> am I missing something here?

Yes. It appears to me that you do not understand

- access modifiers. e.g. `public`, `private`, etc.
- Properties vis-a-vis Fields
- The general idea of information hiding, a.k.a. encapsulation.